# FindElementByID not working with a link in Selenium Webdriver (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't clic a button in Selenium Webdriver using Excel VBA. I have tried with FindElementByXPath, byID, and seems like it does not find the element. I have searched for any iframe in the code but did not find any.

Here is the code:

[image: code]

It calls this function:
[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Maybe there is a frame that you have to switch to. Can you share the link or even the whole html content?

Comment: *"can't click"* and *"nothing worked"* are not good problem descriptions. Please add exception or/and current output

Comment: @YasserKhalil Just posted a bigger piece of the html. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementById*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementById("btaltaP").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("a#btaltaP[name='btalta'][title='Nuevo presupuesto']").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@id='btaltaP' and @name='btalta'][@title='Nuevo presupuesto']").Click
  ```

---

### Update

As it is a `<form>` element you can also try with `Submit` as follows:

- Using *FindElementById*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementById("btaltaP").Submit
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("a#btaltaP[name='btalta'][title='Nuevo presupuesto']").Submit
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@id='btaltaP' and @name='btalta'][@title='Nuevo presupuesto']").Submit
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is not working. That code does not find the element...

Comment: @RebecaB. The element is possibly within an _`overlay`_ you need to add some waits.

Comment: I have added a 10 seconds wait but it is still crashing. I do not know how to handle errors in this case but I think that for some reason it is not finding the button.

Comment: @RebecaB. Can you crosscheck if the element is within an [iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)?

Comment: I've looked it up in the code and I see nothing. I'm going to put a bigger piece of code in the question right now, to see if you can help me with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let  me know the status.

Comment: I have tried with the updated answer but it is not working. When it reaches that instruction it does not generate an error and goes to the next one. However, it does not open the screen that opens when you press the button. Can I call the function instead of pressing the button with Selenium? (I am posting the functions code in the question)

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Sorry but I can not. I can post a picture of how it shows the button if it helps...

Comment: I have tried the IsDisplayed attribute and it returns FALSE. IsEnabled and isPresent both return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it using ClickDouble, so my code is:

bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@id='btaltaP' and @name='btalta'][@title='Nuevo presupuesto']").ClickDouble

Thanks a lot!